How to resolve SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' when running index.js the error?
when adding the Mongodb connection to index.js file and running the very same file an error message is coming up; the code is displayed below:


    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ecommerce-test').then(()=> console.log('Database is connected'))
.catch((err) => console.log(err));

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
reportWebVitals();



When running this code by using 'node index.js' an error message is displaying like this:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
I need to know if this issue is regarding the database connection I setup in the code file or something specific which is unknown for me.

You seem to be missing some quotes.  <React.StrictMode> ... is not valid Javascript.

"I need to know if this issue is regarding the database connection I setup in the code file"  Nope.  "... or something specific which is unknown for me.".  Nope.  This is a simple Javascript syntax error.  Your code needs to be syntactically valid Javascript.  (But this is not specific, and I doubt that is unknown for you ...)

Hint: when the compiler or interpreter says "syntax error" about your code, the first thing you should do is check for syntax errors in your code.

plain js files consider the tags as syntax error. Make sure you save the react files as ".jsx"

@VinayakVohra I have renamed and save the index file as .jsx but nothing really happened. Do you think if I create a new document and set up my database connection only the error could be removed? Thanks
